# How to deal with the optimization problem with non-convex feasible set?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

How to deal with the problem with non-convex feasible set.
\begin{align}
&({\rm P1})\ \underset{\bf x}{\min} f({\bf x})={\bf x}^T{\bf x}+{\bf f}^T{\bf x}\\
&{s.t.}\\
&\|{\bf x}-{\bf x}_z\|_2\geq r,z=1,\cdots,M.\\
&{\bf 1}\leq{\bf x}\leq{\bf 10},
\end{align}
where  $r,M, {\bf x}_z,z=1,\cdots,M$ and $\bf f$ are constant.
I have considered to relax the feasible set to be a convex one to employ SCA by using the first-order Taylor expansion at the solution of the $i$-th iteration ${\bf x}^i$ which is  $\|{\bf x}-{\bf x}_z\|_2\geq\frac{1}{\|{\bf x^i}-{\bf x}_z\|_2}({\bf x^i}-{\bf x}_z)^T({\bf x}-{\bf x}_z)$. Therefore, $(\rm P1)$ can be transformed into
\begin{align}
&({\rm P2})\ \underset{\bf x}{\min} f({\bf x})={\bf x}^T{\bf x}+{\bf f}^T{\bf x}\\
&{s.t.}\\
&\frac{1}{\|{\bf x^i}-{\bf x}_z\|_2}({\bf x^i}-{\bf x}_z)^T({\bf x}-{\bf x}_z)\geq r,z=1,\cdots,M.\\
&{\bf 1}\leq{\bf x}\leq{\bf 10}.
\end{align}
Although $(\rm P2)$ is convex optimization problem, but the feasible set can be empty since the approximation greatly reduce the area of each original non-convex set, and the solution cannot be updated anymore.
I'll really appreciate it if you can give me some insights to deal with the non-convex feasible set with specific structure.

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable?

Comment: Yes, actually it's quadratic function w.r.t. x.

Comment: How big is x? Do you need a global solution? If not, have you tried state-of-the-art nonconvex iterative solvers?

Comment: The length of x is 2. No, I just need a stationary point. As for the state-of-the-art nonconvex iterative solvers, do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Well, one option would be to just use a barrier function, i.e., throw your constraint into a negative logarithm and hope for the best. A more nuanced approach would probably be to use solver software like Uno or SCIP